# problems downloading openjdk on gumstix

Tags: java, packet-sniffers, jpcap, gumstix

From the jpcap installation instructions  http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/install.html, I understand that I need JRE 6 in order for jpcap to work on my Gumstix board. (Is that correct?)

When I tried downloading openjdk-6-java using opkg, it gave me the following error:

```
Downloading http://www.angstrom-distribution.org.........
Collected errors:
* satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for openjdk-6-jre:
*        librhino-java *
* opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package openjdk-6-java
```

I can't find any info about librhino. Could anyone help me with this, please? I am using Gumstix overo with linux angstrom distro version 2.6.34. I also have JamVM version 1.5.3 on my board. I am able to run simple ?HelloWorld java applications, but nothing involving jpcap.

PS: Here's a bit of background: I am trying to download openJDK ONLY because my compiled jpcap file (libjpcap.so) doesn't seem to be visible to any java application that I try to run on gumstix. Not even when I copy it into the same folder (to rule out any path issues). Note that my libpcap is working fine (I used it with a C-language packet sniffer and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to install `librhino-java` with the following:

```
opkg install librhino-java
```

once `librhino-java` is installed you should be able to:

```
opkg install openjdk-6-java
```

If there are more missing dependencies you can look them up here http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/repo/ and and run:

```
opkg install <package_name>
```